# c++ segmentation failed read in .csv file, memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, csv, segmentation-fault

My code should read in from ".csv" file given in the arguments, to a 2D vector table. Everytime I tried to run it it said "Segmentation fault (core dumped). I even tried to get it fiexed with gdb (g++ debugger) in console. The closest I've got to the promblem is this message:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> __memmove_sse2_unaligned_erms () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S:314
> 314   ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S: No such
> file or directory.

I don't know what should I do to fix it.

```
void Table::read_file(std::string f_str) {
    std::fstream file;
    std::string line;
    file.open(f_str, std::ios::in);
    if (!file) { incorrect_input(); }
    else {
        while (std::getline(file, line)) // first while to resize our 2d vector table
        {
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            std::string result;
            int cols = 1;
            while (std::getline(iss, result, sep))
            {
                cols++;
            }
            if (getColumn() < cols) { setColumn(cols); }
            setRow(getRow() + 1);
        }
        file.clear();
        file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while (std::getline(file, line)) // second while to get the records segmented in to our 2d vector table 'cells'
        {
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            std::string result;
            while (std::getline(iss, result, sep))
            {
                cellcontainer[i][j] = result;
                j += 1;
            }
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

**udpate:**
So the cellcontainer is a 2D vector table/matrix. It's constructed by a header file, main calls for it at the start of the code, after the ".csv" file is given through arguments. It contains the "cells" of the 2D vector table. And it looks like this in header:

```
class Table {
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> cellcontainer;
    int row;
    int column;
    char sep = ';';

public:
    Table() : row(1), column(1) {
        cellcontainer.push_back(std::vector<std::string>());
        cellcontainer[0].push_back("-");
    }
```

**update_2:**
I rewrote this line `cellcontainer[i][j] = result;`
To this `cellcontainer.at(i).at(j) = result;`
And it says `std::out_of_range`

Comment: `j` keeps increasing, it's not reset to 0 on each new line. Most likely, `cellcontainer[i][j]` then goes out of bounds.

Comment: `cellcontainer[i][j]` -- You have this in your code, but we have no idea what `cellcontainer` is, where it comes from, how it was initialized, when, where, or how it's used, etc.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm really new to this website. So the cellcontainer is a 2D vector table/matrix. It's constructed by a header file, main calls for it at the start of the code, after the ".csv" file is given through arguments. It contains the "cells" of the 2D vector table. And it looks like this in header: <br/> class Table {
private:
 std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> cellcontainer;
 int row;
 int column;
 char sep = ';';

public:
 Table() : row(1), column(1) {
  cellcontainer.push_back(std::vector<std::string>());
  cellcontainer[0].push_back("-");
 }

Comment: @originalmartin97 `cellcontainer[i][j] = result;` Change that to --> `cellcontainer.at(i).at(j) = result;` -- If that throws a `std::out_of_range` exception, then that's the problem -- either `i` or `j` is out-of-bounds.  Second, update the original question with the code -- don't put the code in the comments.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you. Yeah... my mistake. I will try it.

Comment: "I cannot seem to find why it is out of range." Use a debugger to inspect the values of `i` and `j`, and compare them to `cellcontainer.size()` and `cellcontainer.at(i).size()`.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you, I figured it out. Obviously I was dumb. At the first while() of my code I only kept the columns and rows of the class variables updated and did not even changed the size of my container of the 2D vectors (cellcontainer). Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully for everyone but specially for [Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen).

**solution was:** At the first while() of my code I only kept the columns and rows of the class variables updated and did not even changed the size of my container of the 2D vectors (cellcontainer).

**Now it looks like this:**

```
while (std::getline(iss, result, sep))
    {
        addColumn(1); // <-- addColumn() function arg is an int and it adds to our cellcontainer with resizing.
        cols++;
    }
    if (getColumn() < cols) { setColumn(cols); }
    setRow(getRow() + 1);
    addRow(1); // <-- addRow() function arg is an int and it adds to our cellcontainer with resizing
```